# Javascript for CSS style modification inside Google Chrome browser

Tags: javascript, css, google-chrome

I'm facing a weird problem developing a web application as compatible as possible with most popular browsers :

I've got a HTML  which I want to move inside the page from its original position to another just by clicking on a button.

Here is the HTML code :

`<div id="content">
        text content ...
    </div>`

The associated CSS :

`div#content{
    padding: 15px 15px 15px 215px;
}`

And the javascipt to move the block when clicking on a button :

`document.getElementById('content').style.padding="15px 15px 15px 15px";`

=> It works fine in Firefox, IE and Opera (basically, it expands a content block originally filling half of the page to the full page)

=> Whereas in Chrome, the javascript code doesn't expand the block width but move it of 200px with a fixed width (but if I hard code the padding modifications one at a time, it works fine ...)

I hope to be clear enought :s if anybody has a solution ..
Thanks in advance.

Comment: Your code seems to be doing the opposite of what you're saying; it goes from 215px to 15px. Also a quick test shows no difference between FF 3.5 and Chrome 3.0: http://jsbin.com/ubaru (http://jsbin.com/ubaru/edit)

Comment: Thanks for the answer !
Yes, maybe I've been confused in the movements description ... anyway, I knew this wouldn't be easy to explain, so I uploaded a quick sample of the problem : http://clementjollet.iblogger.org/sandbox/
Here is the exact problem (working as I exactly want in FF, IE and Opera but not in Chrome).

Thx

Comment: Your example, as well as my own test file, both appear to work in Chrome (3.0.195.27). Perhaps this code is right but something else is affecting it? Also, +1 for providing a full sample.

Comment: By "both appear to work in Chrome" you mean that when you test it with this browser, the text content doesn't go out of the right side of the page (and no horizontal scroll bar appears ??) ... Because I've exactly this version of Chrome and the problem persist

Comment: You're right. Somehow I read your question but didn't READ it. Sorry. It definitely appears that Chrome is not properly reevaluating the dimensions of the content tag's children after its altered. I'll see if I can come up with anything.

Comment: Ok ! Thanks once again ... I'll continue digging it. Hope you'll find a way :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you swap the padding for margin it works the same in both Firefox and Chrome (on my PC anyway):

```
div#content{
    padding: 0;
    margin: 15px 15px 15px 15px;
    background: #fff;
}
```

And then:

```
function hideSideBar(){
    document.getElementById('content' ).style.margin="15px 15px 15px 15px";
    document.getElementById('out' ).style.display="none";
    document.getElementById('in' ).style.display="block";
}

function showSideBar(){
    document.getElementById('content').style.margin="15px 15px 15px 215px";
    document.getElementById('out' ).style.display="block";
    document.getElementById('in' ).style.display="none";
}
```

You may have to muck around with some of the rest of your styles to make it look the same.

I think what Chrome is doing is justifiable (not that I've reviewed the specs to check), increasing the padding should naturally make the block wider.

Comment: Pretty simple indeed ! But It works perfectly, thanks a lot Robert !

Answer (score 1):

Adding `overflow: auto;` in the content div CSS seems to fix the problem caused when setting the padding to 215px.

```
#content { padding: 15px 15px 15px 15px; overflow: auto; }
```

You have to use some JavaScript to fix the problem caused when removing the padding:

```
function hideSideBar(){
  var content = document.getElementById('content');
  content.style.padding="15px 15px 15px 15px";

  if (window.getComputedStyle) {
    var para = content.getElementsByTagName('p')[0];

    var paraWidth = window.getComputedStyle(para, null).getPropertyValue('width');
    para.style.width = paraWidth;

    setTimeout(function(){
      para.style.width = 'auto';
    }, 0);
  }

  document.getElementById('out').style.display="none";
  document.getElementById('in').style.display="block";
}
```

Working demo: http://jsbin.com/eqowu (Editable via http://jsbin.com/eqowu/edit)

Comment: I tried it, yes, it solves the problem of the expansion to the right ... but when you click a second time to make it come back, ... wait for it : the content block doesn't re-fit to the window's width and keep the width given by the first javascript snippet ... crap! ><

Comment: A last, but not least THANK YOU for your time Brian ! I tested both of your solution and Robert's one above. They work fine, and I choosed the simplest one with margin property. Thx

Comment: Glad I could help. Remember that you can vote up answers that you find useful ;)

Answer (score 0):

Here is another approach that might be more stable:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01//EN" "http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/strict.dtd">
<html lang="en">
<head>
   <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=utf-8">
   <style type="text/css">

   .MenuHidden #content { padding: 15px 15px 15px 15px; }
   .MenuHidden #out { display: none; }
   .MenuVisible #content { padding: 15px 15px 15px 215px; }
   .MenuVisible #in { display: none; }

   </style>

   <script type="text/javascript">

   function showSideBar(visible) {
      document.body.className = visible ? 'MenuVisible' : 'MenuHidden';
   }

   </script>

</head>

<body class="MenuHidden">

   <div id="header">        
      <div id="out"><a href="#" onclick="showSideBar(false);">Close menu</a></div>
      <div id="in"><a href="#" onclick="showSideBar(true);">Open menu</a></div>
   </div>

   <div id="content">
      <p>
         Donec sodales
         consectetuer nunc. Aenean nec augue. Curabitur commodo, felis at
         tristique venenatis, nunc pede luctus risus, quis eleifend tellus
         mauris eu nisl. Vivamus varius dictum tellus. Nam ornare sem ornare
         justo. Praesent eget magna ut erat ullamcorper adipiscing. Suspendisse
         potenti. Donec lorem. Sed in velit. Maecenas molestie pharetra lacus.
         Donec in velit. In metus tortor, elementum in, porta vitae, posuere eu,
         purus. Quisque quis est. Nunc odio nibh, aliquam eget, ultrices quis,
         dignissim sit amet, augue. Mauris vitae turpis eget ligula porttitor
         nonummy. Etiam pulvinar bibendum tellus. Nam nulla nisl, elementum nec,
         posuere eget, dignissim vel, dolor.
      </p>
   </div>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thanks to you to Guffa ! UNfortunately I just tested it under Chrome 3.0.195.27 and it doesn't change anything ... :(